# Magento2 add multiple buttons in single slide

Tags: magento2

How to add multiple buttons in single slide? We have followed below link for the same
https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/cms/page-builder-media-slider.html#slide-links-and-buttons

From the above link there is section like "Slide links and buttons" and from there is below section like
Method 2: Multiple links or buttons

Can you please explain how can we Add a block placeholder to the slide stage? We have tried it but it is adding into all slides of the slider not for perticular slide.